# Why can't I launch eclipse from a terminal or run it?

Tags: xubuntu, eclipse

Warning:OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0

Comment: Which version of Java and Eclipse are you using? How you installed that?

Comment: openjdk version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.2+9-Ubuntu-3ubuntu118.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: eclipse java oxygen3

Comment: I'm not sure if oxygen is compatible with Java 11. Have you tried proton or newer?

Comment: i tried all answers of that question but not worked for me..

Comment: How exactly did you install eclipse and how exactly are you trying to run it? Please don't just dump terminal output in your question without any further explanation - make it easy for us to help you by including as much detail as you can. Also please add the version info you replied with in comments to your question too.

Comment: I installed eclipse through terminal

Answer (score 1):

From [Migration Guide JDK 8 to JDK 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/migrate/index.html#JSMIG-GUID-055EA9F4-835E-463F-B9E1-9081B3D9E55D) says that in Java 8, Java 9 or Later. the `MaxPermSize` or `PermSize` flag has been removed from Hotspot Heap GC Option and was moved to native memory.

**Removed Permanent Generation**

The permanent generation was removed in JDK 8, and the related VM options cause a warning to be printed. You should remove these options from your scripts:

- XX:MaxPermSize=size
- XX:PermSize=size

In JDK 9 and later releases, the JVM displays a warning like this:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
```

Tools that are aware of the permanent generation may have to be updated.

Or

you can try remove that message using a Environment variable in `.bashrc` :

```
MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx512m
```

Hope this helps.